# MATLAB Trading Toolbox: Why the IB code gets stuck in a for-loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, algorithmic-trading

I am using the Trading Toolbox to establish a connection to the **`IB TWS`**. In general, the API works fine and my code executes my intentions like retrieving real time data and executing orders.

What I would like to do now is executing my code block in a **`for`**-loop ( to run through multiple strategies ), but as soon as I attempt to execute the code in a `for` loop, the code appears to be stuck in an infinite loop, which I can only break by shutting down `MATLAB` ( even a <kbd>`CTRL`</kbd> + <kbd>`c`</kbd>, won't do the trick in this case ).

My command window then rapidly displays `IB` error messages like

> **`Cannot unregister 'xxx'`**,
> where *xxx* is a variety of `IB` functions, such as a `tickPrice`, `tickData`, etc

The odd thing is, that when I manually highlight the code and run it ( with <kbd>F9</kbd> ), everything works like a charm.

From my research, it appears that it has something to do with the way the **`ib`** connection is handled. I open the `ib` connection at the beginning of the `for` loop ( inside of it ) and close it and the end of the loop ( also inside the loop ).

I already attempted to pause the execution for 1-2 seconds after the "close"-command to ensure a sufficient time for the connection to be properly closed, but with no effect.

Can anyone help me out here or has an idea on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: You might already have noticed, that StackOverflow encourages to use an MCVE-based question. Your trouble needs a code to be reproduced so as to confirm the root cause of the problem. There is hard to "find" any answer from air, without an MCVE, but vice-versa the problem isolation and regressive code-unit testing simply leads to result(s). Hope you will find a good & soon advice for your observed problem. MCVE helps a lot in both of these directions. **Anyway, enjoy becoming an active contributing member of this great community of knowledge!**

Comment: As a matter of fact, Interactive Brokers Terms & Conditions might pose a policy restriction on blocking "intensive" re-connections. Normally, the broker-side connection communication gateway gate-keepers do not like frequent setup / close / re-establishing of connections as this may introduce high processing overheads on communication gateways and also might signal some erroneous behaviour of the client-side software component. **Simply said, “Do not rather pat a snake with a bare foot”** ( why would one  “walk into the lion’s den”, wouldn't he ? )

Answer (score 0):

The majority of the problems with the trading toolbox are products of the Matlab built in event handlers.  To solve your problem you need to define a custom event handler for each function that retrieves data.  Also avoid minimizing opening and closing the ib as stated in the comment above.  You can have up to 10 connections if you are running various GUIs, classes, or scripts.

ib=ibtws('1',7496), ib2=ibtws('2',7496)...etc

I recommend wrapping your ibtws controls into classes, this seems to work better than storing them on the base workspace.

Cancel all relevant data requests before closing a GUI or wrapper
ib.Handle.cancelMktData(ReqID);
ib.Handle.cancelMktDepth(ReqID); ...etc

Unfortunately Mathworks built a random number generator (1:10000) to seed the reqIDs for most of their functions.  This often results in duplicate request IDs being sent to IB and can lead to fatal errors. (This is probably the reason they want you to open and close the control so often) Not much you can do about this unless you want to rewrite some of their code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughts! What would be the advantage of having multiple connections (i.e. multiple ActiveX ibtws objects) versus simply having one? I am just getting startet with OOP and Matlab but from what my research shows me, it is defnetly the way to go - do you store all your custom written function handles in a single class or how do you prefer to organize the handling of data requests? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The best reason to use multiple connections is to ensure you will not be completely disconnected by IB if you send in a data request, order etc, that contains an error and results in a disconnect.  At a minimum I recommend running your realtime data, level II data, orders, and historical data requests on separate connections.  This will simplify your event handlers.  I use separate classes for each strategy and related group of functions.  I often write the event handlers as static functions in the class they are associated with or sometimes as separate classes depending on the application.